# how to query from more 2 tables

Tags: php, forum

i tryed to do this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT phpbb_users.user_id, phpbb_users.username, phpbb_users.user_colour, topic_poster, phpbb_topics.forum_id, phpbb_forums.forum_price
FROM phpbb_topics LEFT JOIN phpbb_forums ON phpbb_topics.forum_id = phpbb_forums.forum_id
 LEFT JOIN phpbb_users ON phpbb_topics.topic_poster = phpbb_users.user_id WHERE phpbb_users.group_id = '55222'
 OR phpbb_users.group_id = '55229'
 OR phpbb_users.group_id = '55174'
 GROUP BY phpbb_users.user_id ORDER BY phpbb_forums.forum_price DESC";
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{

    $template->assign_block_vars('earn', array(
        'USER_ID'                   => $row['user_id'],
        'USERNAME'                  => $row['username'],
        'USER_COLOR'                => $row['user_colour'],
        'U_USER'                    => append_sid($phpbb_root_path . "memberlist." . $phpEx . "?mode=viewprofile&u=" . $row['user_id']),
        'TOTAL_EARN'                => $price,
        'TOTAL_UPLOADS'             => $total_price_singels+$total_price_albums,
        'TOTAL_UPLOADS_LASTMONTH'   => $total_upload_lastmonth,
        'TOTAL_UPLOADS_MONTH'       => $total_upload_month,
    ));
}
```

its not work....
I need to query each user to check how many messages he wrote to various forums with each forum has a different price and then get me the price that each user has gained general

thanks again.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? How is it "not work"ing?

Answer (score 0):

if i am correct you dont need that last , after `$total_upload_month`

```
$sql = "SELECT phpbb_users.user_id, phpbb_users.username, phpbb_users.user_colour, topic_poster, phpbb_topics.forum_id, phpbb_forums.forum_priceFROM phpbb_topics LEFT JOIN phpbb_forums ON phpbb_topics.forum_id = phpbb_forums.forum_id LEFT JOIN phpbb_users ON phpbb_topics.topic_poster = phpbb_users.user_id WHERE phpbb_users.group_id = '55222' OR phpbb_users.group_id = '55229' OR phpbb_users.group_id = '55174' GROUP BY phpbb_users.user_id ORDER BY phpbb_forums.forum_price DESC";
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)){
 $template->assign_block_vars('earn', array(        
'USER_ID'                   => $row['user_id'],        
'USERNAME'                  => $row['username'],        
'USER_COLOR'                => $row['user_colour'],        
'U_USER'                    => append_sid($phpbb_root_path . "memberlist." . $phpEx . "?mode=viewprofile&u=" . $row['user_id']),        
'TOTAL_EARN'                => $price,        
'TOTAL_UPLOADS'             => $total_price_singels+$total_price_albums,        
'TOTAL_UPLOADS_LASTMONTH'   => $total_upload_lastmonth,        
'TOTAL_UPLOADS_MONTH'       => $total_upload_month    
));
}
```

Comment: i need to know how to do that... i show you my code that i try and its not work. in my code you can see my tables and the fields that i have. i need to get general price for each user that posting topics in the different forums and each forum have a different price. example: if i post in two forums - forum_id1 and forum_id2 and forum1 = 1$ price, forum2 = 2$ i get in result 3$....  very sorry about my stupid english

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want compulate sum for each user, try something like this:
`SELECT sum(phpbb_forums.price) as total_sum,` ...